Identifying a union piece in furniture and how to disassemble it
I need to disassemble a wooden wardrobe to move it to another room. The wardrobe is made of two modules and they are joined by joining flat the top piece of the lower module and the bottom piece of the upper module. This arrangement doesn't allow access to the keys to disassemble any of the two modules, so it seems that my only option is to separate the modules. Additionally, if I can separate the modules, I don't need to disassemble anything else because once separated bot of them fit through the doors and the corridor.
My problem is that the union is made with a kind of pin that I don't know how to disassemble. In fact, I don't even know its name, so I can't even google it to know if it is intended to be disassembled.



Additional info: there are two similar unions, mounted upside down (that is, one seems to have been mounted top to bottom and the other one bottom to top). The wardrobe is made of particulate board. It was made in Spain in the late 1980s and disassembled, moved to another home and assembled by a professional carpenter in 1990.
In summary, the question:

What is this kind of union called?
Is it supposed to be disassembled when disassembling the furniture?
How can I disassemble it?


To me, the hardware looks incomplete or broken.  Did it look like that originally?

My first suspicion was also that this hardware is lacking a piece that was screwed in that one, but the furniture doesn't move and I can't find any other piece of hardware keeping it in place.

Looks like some kind of nutsert to me, although the middle pic makes me wonder if part of it broke off.

Try searching for phrases like "furniture bolt connector sleeve" or "female bolt".  My suspicion is that this is a type of female bolt with the head broken off.
If it matches the ones I see in the image search, then it's not threaded on the outside.
A few taps with a hammer and screwdriver might be able to punch it out of the hole.
Also, try finding a bolt with matching threads, screw it in part way, then use a hammer claw or pry bar to pull it out.

You were right. I could move one of them with not-so-gentle taps with a screwdriver and a hammer, and then I could move the module and use it as a lever to extract the other one. I can confirm that the connectors weren't threaded on the outside. It makes sense that the male part is missing - although the headless female part alone has get done the job of keeping the parts together for at least 25 years.

Amazing what a little bit of friction and gravity will do for you!
